# Can a Vertex Group be saved as a separate .blend File?

Tags: modeling, export, vertex-groups, makehuman

I've created a model using [makehuman](http://www.makehuman.org/) after editing the hair mesh and recoloring the texture I would like to save this part of the model to be able to reuse it with other models.

Can a part of a mesh (including an armature and material) be saved in another .blend file for importing later?

I tried to select the hair mesh and invert selection to delete everything else, but there are way too many items in the outline view.

EDIT:

The effect after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, *delete all*, <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> is the same as when *append* or *link* will be used to load the hair mesh, unwanted custom shapes and other stuff comes into the new scene.

*Append* `.blend/Mesh/test_clothHairLongMesh2` has no effect at all and *append* `.blend/Object/test_clothHairLongMesh2` loads all the stuff described above.
[image]

Comment: AFAIK, the only way is what you already tried to do.. (delete everything else and save as)

What do you mean by "but there are way too much items in the outline view"?
what didn't work?

(another thing I don't understand is what this has to do with vertex groups?)

Comment: Instead of deleting everything manually in the Outliner, you can Ctrl+C copy your object, select all and delete, then Ctrl+V paste your object back.

Comment: Append blend/Mesh/anyMesh does only unvisible changes. The mesh data is imported into the other blend, but will not get assigned to any object in the scene. Later you can assign it to an existing object (Properties panel / Mesh tab).

Comment: It seems, that the artifacts coming with the appended object have no fases. Maybe because you used the face deletion? Or another possible issue is, that the object also "pulled" its children with it. Make sure nothing has the hair as parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way I can think of is, for safety duplicate
the original object first as you suggested,
then remove the other parts of the mesh:

- Select the part of the mesh to keep.
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to Invert Selection.
- Press <kbd>X</kbd> and Vertices to delete excess parts.

[image: Delete Popup]

Or (not so good solution) you go back to object mode,
select the object if it is not already the only selection,
and export (for example as collada), and check only selected.
Later you can import the exported mesh.

Or you may give a nice name, like APPEND-WITH-ME, and you can
simply append your other blend file and select that object
(not the mesh, the object). Every material, particles,
etc will be also loaded into the new blend file.

Comment: Thanks, your comments about the invisible Mesh and Parenting are probably the key. I will check that soon.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to invert selection without involving Outliner space. After displaying all layers <kbd>~</kbd>, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, or **Select** > **Inverse Selection**, in the 3D View space:

[image: 1]

But to reuse a component of your character, you don't need to save it to a different file. Just make sure every object and obdata are properly named: what is the object, and which character it is a part of. That way, when you append or link from another file, it's always clear which data you need just from its name. This illustration is in Indonesian, but I hope it's clear enough that I've followed such naming convention:

[image: 2]

I made this task easier for myself, by having a regexp-based renaming operator (to easily add prefix or replace some suffixes) and obdata<->object name syncing operator in my personal [rigging tool](https://github.com/adhihargo/rigging_tools/).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Ahdi, Gwenn, and Róbert László Páli's answers:

Deleting the extra objects is actually unnecessary, but it makes things a lot easier to find when it's time to append your objects. (Unless you have a good naming system so you can identify what object is which)

- **To delete extra parts of mesh:**
  Select the part of the mesh you want to keep:

  [image]

  Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or *3D view > Select > Inverse* to invert the selection:

  [image] [image]

  Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd> and select *Vertices* to delete unwanted parts of the mesh:

  [image]
- **Deleting extra objects:**
  If you have extra objects that you do not want that are not part of the wanted mesh,   you can delete them by going into *Object mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and:

  (Note: you may want to make all layers visible (<kbd>~</kbd>) and un-hide all objects (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) before doing this.)

  Selecting **only** your wanted object(s), use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or *3D view > Select > Inverse* to invert the selection again, and then *delete* (<kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd>)

You can now save your file with ***Save As*** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or *Info Panel > File > Save As*)

Whenever you want to use that object again, you can (in your other file) [*Append* or *Link* objects](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Linked_Libraries#Appending_library_objects_into_your_current_project)

- **Appending:**
  (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or *Info Panel > File > Append*)
  navigate to the blendfile with the wanted object, go into *Object*, then select the objects you want and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or *Link/Append from library*
- **Copy / Paste:**

  Also, as mentioned by Gwenn, Cut, Copy, and Paste were added in [Blender 2.66](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.66/Usability#Copy.2Fpaste_Objects_in_3D_window)

  So you can simply select and *Copy* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) your objects out of Blender, then in a new instance of Blender (or after opening your other file in the current instance) *Paste* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't actually need to save a separate file to do this. Just save the file with everything in it as you normally would, then open a new file (or the file you want the object in), go to File> Append, and select your specific object from the file browser. That should place a full copy (materials, mesh, textures, etc) into your new file.

Comment: Thanks I tried both of your suggestions and edited my question.